# Boto s3 get_metadata

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, boto

Trying to get meta_data that i have set on all my items in an s3 bucket. Which can be seen in the screenshot and below is the code I'm using. The two get_metadata calls return None. Any idea's

[image]

> > > boto.Version
> > >       '2.5.2'

```
amazon_connection = S3Connection(ec2_key, ec2_secret)
  bucket = amazon_connection.get_bucket('test')
  for key in bucket.list():
    print " Key %s " % (key)
    print key.get_metadata("company")
    print key.get_metadata("x-amz-meta-company")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

bucket.list() does not return metadata. try this instead:

```
for key in bucket.list():
   akey = bucket.get_key(key.name)
   print akey.get_metadata("company")
```

Comment: You can also use head_object https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object to get the metadata without having to get the object itself. (Probably didn't exist at the time this answer was written, but useful to those still landing here from google searches as I did.)