# Not able to get_metadata for AWS S3 object using Python Boto-2.48

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to get_metadata() which I have set on all my items(objects) in an s3 bucket. The get_metadata calls return None.

I am using Python 2.7 & Boto 2.48. Following is my code.

```
    for key in bucket:

    key = bucket.get_key(key.name)
    print key
    if key is not None:
        print key.name, key.get_metadata('Cache-Control'), key.get_metadata('Content-Type'), key.get_metadata('Expires')
```

Output:

> images/xyz.jpg None None None

I have already tried suggestions mentioned on following link,
[Boto s3 get_metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979199/boto-s3-get-metadata)
https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/570

Please suggest if I am missing something here!

Comment: `get_metadata` is for *custom metadata*.  `get_metadata('foo')` refers to the value of `x-amz-meta-foo`.  It isn't for the system/identity metadata like `Cache-Control`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me.

```
for key in bucket:

    key = bucket.get_key(key.name)

    if key is not None:
        print key.name, key.cache_control, key.content_type, key.expires
```

Interestingly, key.expires is not mentioned in [documentation](http://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key) still it worked for me.